# Oracle Sql: filter based on largest column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to construct an oracle sql query to result unique rows based on an ordered value. I think showing an example is easiest:

Let's say I have a table that looks as such:

```
Table 1

id   A    B
--------------
0   a_0  b_0
1   a_1  b_0
2   a_2  b_1
3   a_3  b_1
4   a_4  b_2
5   a_5  b_2
6   a_6  b_2
      ...
```

I would like to return a table with *unique* B values, such that the A value is the *largest* value.

Table Result

```
id   A    B
--------------
0   a_0  b_0
1   a_3  b_1
2   a_5  b_2
      ...
```

where `a_0 > a_1`, `a_3 > a_2`, `a_5 > a_4 and a_5 > a_6`, ...

Is this possible to due in a single query (subqueries, plsql, etc... is fine).

I am able to due this trivially in spark, but I don't know how to do this in sql.

Comment: how can this happen?  a_5 > a_4 and a_5 > a_6 @john

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select id, a, b
from table1 t
where t.a = (select max(t2.a) from table1 t2 where t2.b = t.b);
```

With an index on `(a, b)`, this might be the fastest method.

Another fun method is aggregation:

```
select max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by a desc) as id,  max(a) as a, b
from table1 t
group by b;
```

Actually, Oracle is very good with aggregation performance, so this could also perform very well.

Also  you can check the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8c3e8/8).

Comment: But these queries don't give **unique B values**, please see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8c3e8/3

Comment: @krokodilko, it is easy, just swap a, b in above sql.

Comment: @Sphinx i've spapped a and b, and still b is not unique, please see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8c3e8/13

Comment: @krokodilko . . . Run the query in the edited question.